# How Can I display data coming from a database using ASP.NET & HTML

Tags: asp.net, html, sql

I made a query that retrieve a list of items from a database:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetSubjects(@DayComing varchar(10) , @UserId varchar(3))
    AS
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT        Std_ID
    FROM            Student
    WHERE Std_ID = @UserID) 
    BEGIN

    SELECT        TimeTable.Ttb_Subject 
    FROM            Student INNER JOIN
                       Class ON Student.Std_Class = Class.Cls_ID INNER JOIN
                       TimeTable ON Class.Cls_ID = TimeTable.Ttb_Class
     WHERE        (TimeTable.Ttb_WeekDay = @DayComing) AND (Student.Std_ID = @UserID)

     END
     ELSE BEGIN

     SELECT        TimeTable.Ttb_Subject, TimeTable.Ttb_Class
     FROM            Teacher INNER JOIN
                        TimeTable ON Teacher.Tch_ID = TimeTable.Ttb_Teacher
     WHERE        (TimeTable.Ttb_WeekDay = @DayComing)

     END
```

Now I want to show m at  asp page, but I don't know how can I do it. Do you know any tutorials that can help me with this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options, for example Linq2Sql, Linq2EF, ADO.NET, some other framework...

Here's a tut on how to accomplish this with ado.net:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15403/Calling-Stored-procedures-in-ADO-NET

Here's how you do it with Linq 2 SQL:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

And Linq 2 Entity framework:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Awesome Tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options. Have a look at the below source:

[ASP.NET Data Controls](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/aspnet-data-controls)

Also, you may prefer to work with an ORM technology like Entity Framework:

[Working with Data (Entity Framework Tutorial)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/working-with-data-%28entity-framework-tutorial%29)