# Can't convert ISingleResult to IEnumerable

Tags: sql, list, type-conversion, ienumerable

I'm trying to display a list coming from my database using Linqtosql but I guess I'm making it wrong.

I wrote the SPROC to retrieve the data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008489/how-can-i-display-data-coming-from-a-database-using-asp-net-html) if you want further info: 
 And this is my  code:

```
     protected List<MySubject> GetSubjects(int userID, string Datetime)
    {
        userID = user_id;
        string[] dates = Datetime.Split('-');
        int year = int.Parse(dates[2]);
        int month = int.Parse(dates[1]);
        int day = int.Parse(dates[0]);
        ClassDAO classClass = new ClassDAO();
        List<MySubject> myTodaySubjects = GetSubjectsLinq(userID, day);
        GetSubjectsLinq(userID, day);
        return myTodaySubjects;
    }

    private List<MySubject> GetSubjectsLinq(int UserId, int day)
    {
        MySchoolDBDataContext db = new MySchoolDBDataContext();
        string Suserid = UserId.ToString();
        string Sday = day.ToString();
        var sub = db.GetSubjects(Sday , Suserid);
        return sub.ToList<MySubject>();
     }
```

This Line `"return sub.ToList<MySubject>();"` shows this error :

```
Error   21  Instance argument: cannot convert from 
'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
```

Do you know how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your

> db.GetSubjects (Sday , Suserid);

method(stored procedure). It looks like it is returning only one single value of a certain type, which means that it cannot be assigned to an `IEnumerable<T>` such as a `List<T>`.

Since you use a stored procedure in LINQ, it'll generate a class T(procedure name + "Result") for you automatically to store the data. The returned type is always `ISingleResult<T>`.

So, you can try the following:

```
ISinlgeResult<MySubjectResult> sub = db.GetSubjects(Sday , Suserid);
foreach(MySubjectResult val in sub)
{
...
}
```

or just use `db.GetSubjects (Sday , Suserid).ReturnValue;`

Comment: @OnlyHope - Try one of the two ways I noted in the answer. The result you are looking for is actually wrapped in ISingleResult.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have another question:
When I use db.GetSubjects (Sday , Suserid).ReturnValue; what will the returned value be ?

Answer (score 1):

Was looking everywhere for the same problem and finding only all those `foreach` loops - but then for me worked the most simple thing `.ToList()`:

```
return db.GetSubjects(Sday , Suserid).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways you can return a stored proc results ... see below

public YourDataContext context;

//assuming Json return

```
public JsonResult GetResults(string param1, string param2) 
{
    using(context = new YourDataContext())
    {
       return Json(context.YourStoredProc(param1, param2).ToList<YourStoredProcResult>());
     }
}
```

//Assuming just complex return

```
 public List<YourStoredProcResult> GetResults(string param1, string param2)
        {
            using(context = new dataDataContext())
            {
                return context.YourStoredProc(param1, param2).ToList<YourStoredProcResult>();
            }
        }
```

//There is other ways....